# Debain Path Issue with Play Framework Installation

Tags: playframework, path

I'm installing the Java Play framework on Debian and running into issues getting the hello world example to execute.  It seems to be a "PATH" issue.

```
root@Home:/home/myuser/play-2.2.5/helloworld# play
bash: play: command not found
```

The $PATH variable seems to be set correctly, but I still get the error.

```
root@Home:/home/myuser# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/myuser/play-2.2.5/play
```

This is the line in my .bashrc (and .profile as I've tried both)

```
export PATH="$PATH":/home/myuser/play-2.2.5/play
```

How should I troubleshoot from here?

Comment: Is `/home/myuser/play-2.2.5/play` the pull path to the play binary, or the directory that contains it?

Comment: the full path to the binary

Comment: It should be the latter. Try `/home/myuser/play-2.2.5` in your `PATH`, instead.

Comment: That worked, submit as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When appending to your path, you need to append the absolute path to the directory that contains the binary you want to execute, and not the full path to the binary itself. This is because the `PATH` variable tells the shell where to look for executable files.

So if `play` is located within `/home/myuser/play-2.2.5`, then

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/myuser/play-2.2.5
```